# Yoast Seo breadcrumbs: How to add custom text to category and tag name

Tags: wordpress, breadcrumbs, yoast

In yoast SEO breadcrumbs I would like to add a fixed text before the category name and the tag: It should look like this:

Home -> Blog -> Category: NameCategory
or
Home -> Blog -> Selected tag: NameTag

I'm looking for a code.

Comment: Does this answer to your question https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/350538/yoast-seo-breadcrumbs-how-to-create-a-filter-that-uses-the-url-slug-for-breadcr ? (I would any recommand that you ask the same question in this area of stack https://wordpress.stackexchange.com )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution that works :)

```
add_filter('wpseo_breadcrumb_single_link', 'filter_breadcrumbs_for_h1', 10, 2);
function filter_breadcrumbs_for_h1($link_output, $link) {

    if ( is_category()  ) {
    $link_output = preg_replace("/<span\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/span>/is", "<span $1>Category: ''$2''</span>", $link_output);
    return $link_output;
    }

    else if ( is_tag()  ) {
        $link_output = preg_replace("/<span\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/span>/is", "<span $1>Tag: ''$2''</span>", $link_output);
        return $link_output;
        }

    else  {
        $link_output = preg_replace("/<span\s(.+?)>(.+?)<\/span>/is", "<span $1>$2</span>", $link_output);
        return $link_output;
        }

}
```